# Convert a JSON style String to a map Groovy in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a string that looks like this `{"analyzer": "static_analyzer", "status": "success", "hash": "3c8f0dae82136f0a1447de5531e5bd03", "scan_type": "zip", "file_name": "jenkins-iOS-BuildVerify-GH-PR-6487-38.zip"}`. I want to parse this and get the value of "hash", but I can't find any existing methods to convert this into a map.

Comment: Just try to google `jenkins json parse` - there are so many examples...

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are working with a Jenkins pipeline. If so You can do something like the below. Here I'm using the inbuilt `readJSON` option. You can read more [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace).

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Sample') {
          steps {
            script {
                def jsonString = '{"analyzer": "static_analyzer", "status": "success", "hash": "3c8f0dae82136f0a1447de5531e5bd03", "scan_type": "zip", "file_name": "jenkins-iOS-BuildVerify-GH-PR-6487-38.zip"}'
                def props = readJSON text: jsonString
                def hash = props['hash']
                echo "$hash"
            }
          }
    }
    }
}
```